# Flutter issue: Getting error on multi line description value

Tags: flutter

I have a multi line description which looks like below:

```
List<Hymnal> _items = [
Hymnal(
    id: '1',
    indexNumber: '001',
    title: 'O Worship the Lord',
    hymns: 
    " 1
      O worship the Lord in the beauty of holiness,
      Bow down before Him, His glory proclaim;
      With gold of obedience, and incense of lowliness,
      Kneel and adore Him: the Lord is His name.")];
```

The above line is causing some issues because I guess of the format of hymns. This is hard coded and I just put it inside Hymns.dart. 
Any advice on what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiline Strings, you have to use three quotation marks:

```
hymns: 
  ''' 1
   O worship the Lord in the beauty of holiness,
   Bow down before Him, His glory proclaim;
   With gold of obedience, and incense of lowliness,
   Kneel and adore Him: the Lord is His name.'''
```

[This](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/String-class.html) can help.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I didn't know that it's also included in the documentation. Maybe, I just don't know what key search to type in google that's why I have difficulty in solving this problem. Thanks Morez!